# How to deal with multiple Data Type in cython?

Tags: numpy, scipy, cython, python-c-api

What are the different techniques to deal with multiple data types in cython? How can I make the code generic for multiple data types and on the same hand maintain efficiency as well.

Comment: You need to be more specific, giving evidence that you have studied the cython documentation, and even tried a few things.

Answer (score 0):

1) Fused types, which as you now know from your previous question [Alternatives of fused type in cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256582/alternatives-of-fused-type-in-cython) are fine

2) write your code in c++ using templates and wrap that

3) code duplication, possibly using a diy script you wrote yourself

4) using plain python which deals with types generically where they have the same interface and has introspection where they don't